# Add new item count to icon on button - Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm developer. I need to implement design shown below. I already have functional app but wonder how to even approach this? Particulary, I'm interested in how to show Number of "New" items under tabs. What I KNOW how to do - is create new icons with red dots and just display them when new stuff available.

But I have no idea how to make those round circles float on top of title AND show number inside. Does anybody have suggestion on what too look for? Samples? Directions?

Second question about separating activities. Should I make control to combine buttons like this and just inflate it on activities? Otherwise I may create tabbed activity but I'm not sure if it's possible to style it to make it look like this.

[image: Portion of top navigation]

Answer (score 168, accepted):

Make your badge a `TextView`, allowing you to set the numeric value to anything you like by calling `setText()`.  Set the background of the `TextView` as an XML `<shape>` drawable, with which you can create a solid or gradient circle with a border.  An XML drawable will scale to fit the view as it resizes with more or less text.

**res/drawable/badge_circle.xml:**

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:shape="oval">
  <solid
    android:color="#F00" />
  <stroke
    android:width="2dip"
    android:color="#FFF" />
  <padding
    android:left="5dip"
    android:right="5dip"
    android:top="5dip"
    android:bottom="5dip" />
</shape>
```

You'll have to take a look at how the oval/circle scales with large 3-4 digit numbers, though.  If this effect is undesirable, try a rounded rectangle approach like below.  With small numbers, the rectangle will still look like a circle as the radii converge together.

**res/drawable/badge_circle.xml:**

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:shape="rectangle">
  <corners
    android:radius="10dip"/>
  <solid
    android:color="#F00" />
  <stroke
    android:width="2dip"
    android:color="#FFF" />
  <padding
    android:left="5dip"
    android:right="5dip"
    android:top="5dip"
    android:bottom="5dip" />
</shape>
```

With the scalable background created, you simply add it to the background of a `TextView`, like so:

```
<TextView
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
  android:text="10"
  android:textColor="#FFF"
  android:textSize="16sp"
  android:textStyle="bold"
  android:background="@drawable/badge_circle"/>
```

Finally, these `TextView` badges can be placed in your layout on top of the appropriate buttons/tabs.  I would probably do this by grouping each button with its badge in a `RelativeLayout` container, like so:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">
  <Button
    android:id="@+id/myButton"
    android:layout_width="65dip"
    android:layout_height="65dip"/>
  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textOne"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/myButton"
    android:layout_alignRight="@id/myButton" 
    android:text="10"
    android:textColor="#FFF"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:background="@drawable/badge_circle"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Hopefully that's enough information to at least get you pointed in the right direction!

Comment: Is it possible to do something similar to this with a TableLayout? I have a 2x2 grid of buttons and a relative layout is more of a pain to setup than a relative layout however I can't use attributes like aligntTop and alignRight

Comment: NM I solved it by just putting a relative layout in the table row! Thanks, code works great

Comment: Nice code man! thanks! If it will not bother you, how could I make a more rounded oval? :)

Comment: @FelipeMosso Use the `oval` version of the example and add a `<size>` element to provide proportions for the width/height

Comment: Count icon is hiding behind that button in my case. On Android 5.0. Don't know what's wrong. In graphical layout it looks good but not in device.

Comment: If I use Button for count icon, everything works fine but if I use Textview it goes behind main button instead of showing up on top!

Comment: hey @Devunwired badge is not display in android 5.0 devise. what is the solution for android 5.0?

Comment: badge.settext(data.size())  is giving me nullPointerException, i have also tried *badge.settext( Integer.toString(data.size))* and String.valueOf(allWords.size) sp help me plz to resolve nullpointerException

Comment: To avoid count icon being rendered behind button, try set `translationZ` or `elevation` to icon.

Comment: this is the best idea without any library

Answer (score 11):

**Android ViewBadger**

A simple way to "badge" any given Android view at runtime without having to cater for it in layout.

Add `.jar` file in your libs folder

[Click to download](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-viewbadger/archive/master.zip) Example

see [Example](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-viewbadger) on github

Simple example:

```
View target = findViewById(R.id.target_view);
BadgeView badge = new BadgeView(this, target);
badge.setText("1");
badge.show();
```

Comment: This library is deprecated.

Answer (score 4):

Simplest hack by giving style to `TextView` only.

```
        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/fabCounter"
                style="@style/Widget.Design.FloatingActionButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="10"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="14sp" />
```

> [image: Result]

Answer (score 4):

Just to add. If someone wants to implement a filled circle bubble using the ring shape instead of oval, here's the code example of adding the bubble count to action bar buttons. But this can be added to any button.

(name it `bage_circle.xml`):

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="ring"
    android:useLevel="false"
    android:thickness="9dp"
    android:innerRadius="0dp"
    >

    <solid
        android:color="#F00"
        />
    <stroke
        android:width="1dip"
        android:color="#FFF" />

    <padding
        android:top="2dp"
        android:bottom="2dp"/>

</shape>
```

You may have to adjust the thickness according to your need.

The result will be something like this:

[image]

Here's the layout for button (name it `badge_layout.xml`):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <com.joanzapata.iconify.widget.IconButton
        android:layout_width="44dp"
        android:layout_height="44dp"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:background="@drawable/action_bar_icon_bg"
        android:id="@+id/badge_icon_button"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/badge_textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/badge_icon_button"
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/badge_icon_button"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@id/badge_icon_button"
        android:text="10"
        android:paddingEnd="8dp"
        android:paddingRight="8dp"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        android:textSize="11sp"
        android:background="@drawable/badge_circle"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

In Menu create item:

```
<item
        android:id="@+id/menu_messages"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:actionLayout="@layout/badge_layout"/>
```

In `onCreateOptionsMenu` get reference to the Menu item:

```
    itemMessages = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_messages);

    badgeLayout = (RelativeLayout) itemMessages.getActionView();
    itemMessagesBadgeTextView = (TextView) badgeLayout.findViewById(R.id.badge_textView);
    itemMessagesBadgeTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE); // initially hidden

    iconButtonMessages = (IconButton) badgeLayout.findViewById(R.id.badge_icon_button);
    iconButtonMessages.setText("{fa-envelope}");
    iconButtonMessages.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.action_bar_icon_color_disabled));

    iconButtonMessages.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (HJSession.getSession().getSessionId() != null) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(getThis(), HJActivityMessagesContexts.class);
                startActivityForResult(intent, HJRequestCodes.kHJRequestCodeActivityMessages.ordinal());
            } else {
                showLoginActivity();
            }
        }
    });
```

After receiving notification for messages, set the count:

```
itemMessagesBadgeTextView.setText("" + count);
itemMessagesBadgeTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
iconButtonMessages.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
```

This code uses [Iconify-fontawesome](https://github.com/JoanZapata/android-iconify).

```
compile 'com.joanzapata.iconify:android-iconify-fontawesome:2.1.+'
```

Answer (score 1):

for the people who are looking for Xamarin Android Can Use This Code

```
public class CountDrawable : Drawable
{
    private float mTextSize;
    private Paint mBadgePaint;
    private Paint mTextPaint;
    private Rect mTxtRect = new Rect();

    private String mCount = "";
    private bool mWillDraw = false;


    public CountDrawable(Context context)
    {
        float mTextSize = context.Resources.GetDimension(Resource.Dimension.badge_count_textsize);
        mBadgePaint = new Paint();
        // mBadgePaint.SetCol(ContextCompat.GetColor(context.ApplicationContext, Resource.Color.background_color));
        mBadgePaint.Color = new Color(Color.Red);
        mBadgePaint.AntiAlias = true;
        mBadgePaint.SetStyle(Paint.Style.Fill);

        mTextPaint = new Paint();
        mTextPaint.Color = new Color(Color.White);
        mTextPaint.SetTypeface(Typeface.DefaultBold);
        mTextPaint.TextSize = mTextSize;
        mTextPaint.AntiAlias = true;
        mTextPaint.TextAlign = Paint.Align.Center;
    }


    public override void Draw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        if(!mWillDraw)
        {
            return;
        }



        Rect bounds = GetBounds;
        float width = bounds.Right - bounds.Left;
        float height = bounds.Bottom - bounds.Top;

        float radius = ((Math.Max(width, height) / 2)) / 2;
        float centerX = (width - radius - 1) + 5;
        float centerY = radius - 5;
        if (mCount.Length <= 2)
        {
            // Draw badge circle.
            canvas.DrawCircle(centerX, centerY, (int)(radius + 5.5), mBadgePaint);
        }
        else
        {
            canvas.DrawCircle(centerX, centerY, (int)(radius + 6.5), mBadgePaint);
        }

        mTextPaint.GetTextBounds(mCount, 0, mCount.Length, mTxtRect);
        float textHeight = mTxtRect.Bottom - mTxtRect.Top;
        float textY = centerY + (textHeight / 2f);
        if (mCount.Length > 2)
            canvas.DrawText("99+", centerX, textY, mTextPaint);
        else
            canvas.DrawText(mCount, centerX, textY, mTextPaint);
    }

    public Rect GetBounds { get; set; }


    public void setCount(String count)
    {
        mCount = count;

        // Only draw a badge if there are notifications.
       // mWillDraw = !count.equalsIgnoreCase("0");
        mWillDraw = !string.Equals(count, "0", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
       // invalidateSelf();
    }

    public override void SetAlpha(int alpha)
    {

    }

    public override void SetColorFilter(ColorFilter colorFilter)
    {

    }

    public override int Opacity
    {
        get;
    }

}
```

And in MainActivity

```
public override bool OnCreateOptionsMenu(IMenu menu)
    {
        // return base.OnCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        MenuInflater.Inflate(Resource.Menu.actionmenu, menu);
        // var dd = menu.FindItem(Resource.Id.icon_group);
        IMenuItem item = menu.FindItem(Resource.Id.ic_group);
        LayerDrawable icon = item.Icon as LayerDrawable;

        // LayerDrawable icon = (LayerDrawable)item.Icon;
        CountDrawable badge;
        Drawable reuse = icon.FindDrawableByLayerId(Resource.Id.ic_group_count);
        if (reuse != null && reuse is CountDrawable)
        {
            badge = (CountDrawable)reuse;
        }
        else
        {
            badge = new CountDrawable(this);

        }
        badge.setCount("8");
        badge.GetBounds=icon.Bounds;

        icon.Mutate();
        icon.SetDrawableByLayerId(Resource.Id.ic_group_count, badge);
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: how do i make the circle smaller ?

Comment: @khalil try to create using SkiaSharp