# Show notification list like facebook

Tags: android-notifications

I new on Android development.I need to show notification on click icon like facebook .

I have using link:
[How to make an icon in the action bar with the number of notification?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18156477/how-to-make-an-icon-in-the-action-bar-with-the-number-of-notification)
Please help me

Thanks in Advance