# How to update AppBar icon notification(State) from event implemented in different class?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

My requirement is something like this:
[Flutter - change appbar icon when receiving notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55730390/flutter-change-appbar-icon-when-receiving-notification)

But AppBar 'cart icon' which is to be notified on 'addToCart' button click implemented in another dart file. Am I doing something wrong by placing the AppBar and the rest in two different dart files? Let me know how to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a global `ValueNotifier` variable. Then you can change it's content regardless the page in which you are.

Assuming this variable declaration `ValueNotifier cartCounterNotifier = ValueNotifier(0);`, you can update your `AppBar` action like this

```
appBar: AppBar(
    // title and other
    actions: [
      ValueListenableBuilder(
          valueListenable: cartCounterNotifier,
          builder: (context, cartCounter, child) {
            return Stack(
              children: [
                IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.shopping_cart_rounded),
                  onPressed: () {},
                ),
                Positioned(
                  child: 0 < cartCounter ? Container(
                    decoration: ShapeDecoration(
                      color: Colors.red,
                      shape: CircleBorder(),
                    ),
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
                    child: Text("$cartCounter", style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),),
                  ) : SizedBox(),
                ),
              ],
            );
          }
      )
    ],
  ),
```

**Update:** 
So to update your action button, simply change the content of your variable like this

```
cartCounterNotifier.value = cartCounterNotifier.value + 1; // or another value
```

Comment: thanks for quick reply. I gone through <https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ValueListenableBuilder-class.html>. Let me correct my question: AppBar cart icon which is to be notified on 'addToCart' click implemented on another dart file instead of another class.

Comment: not yet :) . please read my above comment for reframed question