# Android how to add badge to button

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to add a badge in my button, how can i do that ?

[image]

Button :

```
                    <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/badge_circle"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="12dip"
                    android:text="Button"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"/>
```

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6011786/add-new-item-count-to-icon-on-button-android

Comment: Check thjis link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60751801/9764941

Answer (score 6):

You can use this

```
BadgeDrawable badgeDrawable =  BadgeDrawable.create(getContext());
badgeDrawable.setNumber(3);
badgeDrawable.setVisible(true);
BadgeUtils.attachBadgeDrawable(badgeDrawable, tragetView);
```

check for more https://material.io/develop/android/components/badging

Answer (score 2):

Need to set the compound drawable of the button.
Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4502605/how-to-programatically-set-drawableleft-on-android-button) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8318765/how-do-i-use-a-compound-drawable-instead-of-a-linearlayout-that-contains-an-imag) for better understandment.
If u have any more questions. ask.

Answer (score 2):

Use this [library](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-viewbadger)

Sample example provided by library

```
View target = findViewById(R.id.target_view);
BadgeView badge = new BadgeView(this, target);
badge.setText("1");
badge.show();
```

Also check this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6011786/add-new-item-count-to-icon-on-button-android/6039353#6039353)