# Android display notification number next to menu item

Tags: android, menu, android-notifications, menuitem

I want to display a notification number on a menu item in the overflow stack to indicate there are x updates available. I know you can set an icon to the menu item, but I want to display the number on the right side of the menu item (Instabridge does this to indicate hotspot index is bein updated). How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would assume that the overflow stack you're talking about is the OverflowPopup. If not, these two questions may solve your problem: [Actionbar notification count icon (badge) like Google has](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17696486/actionbar-notification-count-icon-like-google-have/26017587#26017587), and [Add new item count to icon on button - Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6011786/add-new-item-count-to-icon-on-button-android).

For the popup, you may want to create a custom menu view for the notification number, as this pattern is not supported by the library. (There may be better ways of doing that.)

However, creating a custom menu view is a little bit complicated. Here is what I got from reading the source, not tested!

First, You need to create your **MenuView.ItemView** and add notification number to it. You can either create a new view that implementes this interface or use android's **android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView**.

Then, You need a customized **ActionMenuPresenter** to use your menu view. In the **ActionMenuPresenter** you can change the constructor's second parameter to your view.

```
public ActionMenuPresenter(Context context) {
    super(context, R.layout.abc_action_menu_layout, R.layout.abc_action_menu_item_layout);
}
```

or override **BaseMenuPresenter.createItemView** method.

Finally, you need to wire up the **ActionMenuPresenter** with your Toolbar.

Please reference the source code for more details.