# Small bubble over a button to count items added to cart?

Tags: android, xml

I want to make a small bubble over a button in android which essentially tell the number of times the button is clicked or added items to the cart. I believe its called badges in iOS environment, I don't know about android, but this is what I want to achieve:

[image: bubble over button]

I also found a working solution here: [Add new item count to icon on button - Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6011786/add-new-item-count-to-icon-on-button-android)

But this doesn't work on Android 5.0+. In 5.0+ versions the bubble is hidden behind the button completely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Working solution code if your arrange the button and the textview  in Grid according to your need than it will solve your problem 
Find more about Gridview [Here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html)

Comment: ok, I will give it a try , but why does the same code with RelativeLayout not work in Android 5.0 and higher?

Comment: Only the layout problem in 5.0 and higher ?

Comment: yes , it works fine on kitkat , but in lollipop, the textview is hidden behind the button completely

Comment: Use the Tablelayout or Grid Layout It will solve your problem

Comment: ok , in GridLayout , the textview is visible , but I want it to be placed above the button , with its edges slightly touching the button, like shown in the image in the question.

Comment: Make one cell gravity right (button cell )and other left (textview cell)

Comment: Same Issue textview still behind the button ?

Comment: no, textview is visible but some sort of gap between textview and button

Comment: Merge both the cells