# Xamarin Android displaying count of notifications

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, notifications, icons

I working with Xamarin.Android project, and I need to displaying count of notifications (badge): a white number in red circle near the application icon on **desktop**. How can I implement it? For example: it should looks the same just as if I recieve new message in WhatsApp, or SMS.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add new item count to icon on button - Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6011786/add-new-item-count-to-icon-on-button-android)

Comment: @Ronak Shethia unfortinately not. I need to display a badge with app icon on phone's desktop, but that question is about how to display badge inside app.